# GitHub collaborator private profile

Tags: git, github

Is necessary that GitHub collaborator has private(paid) profile if it should work as a collaborator on the private project. It is possible on BitBucket but I don't know how it works on GitHub.

Thank you in advance for response.

Answer (score 0):

No, any GitHub user can collaborate on a private project.  Only the user or organization hosting a private repository need have a paid account.